# How to make Spell list in Oblivion smaller?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have downloaded wz_inventory mod but it only compress the items inventory. How to make the spell list smaller so that i can view more spells without scrolling?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Darnified UI](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=10763) is the exact solution. It decrease the font size in of all boxes, compresses the size of HUD, enlarges the map, make font and icon of inventory and spell list smaller.... See the two example images below
[image]
[image]
 Darnified UI+wz_inventory is also a good combination.

Comment: nice plugin, didn't know that until now =) thx

Answer (score 8):

You should try the plugin "Clean Spellbook", it helps you managing your spells in a proper way. Spells are sorted by category, you can hide spells and restore them to be visible any time you want to!

[Clean Spellbook](http://www.planetoblivion.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1310&Itemid=73)

Comment: Where are the screenshots?

Comment: Please explain the installation method also. It is difficult. I have downloaded and installed OBSE now what to do with Clean SpellBook

Comment: ok, you installed the OBSE, now you just have to unzip the content of "Clean Spellbook" into your \Bethesda Softworks\Oblivion\Data Folder. Then Start Oblivion-Launcer and activate the Plugin through the "Data File"-Option. Screenshot follows.

Comment: It doesn't make the spell list smaller, it adds a new item Spell Book in inventory. That's bad. If just the spell list is smaller it would be a lot easier. I don't know why wz_inventory didn't make a mod for spell list.

Comment: @Life yes you get a Spell-Book where ALL Spells are listed, but in your standard Spell-List there should only be those Spells you want to see!

Comment: Do you know any other mod that can compress the size of spell list, something like wz_inventory did for inventory?

Comment: Sry certainly not! I always walked good with clean spellbook

Comment: Ah i know the answer, now i am using Darnified UI and it is exactly what i wanted. Darnified UI+wz_inventory is also a good combination

Comment: @Iceag There seems to be a later version of the [Clean Spellbook mod here (v2.0.3)](http://www.worldofelderscrolls.de/?go=dlfile&fileid=133), compared to the [one in the planetoblivion.de page you linked above (v1.3.0)](http://www.planetoblivion.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1310&Itemid=73). Have you tried this?